# Modify keyboard config file

Tags: 12.04, keyboard-layout

Being a French Canadian, I like to have easy access to accents like èéÀ, but would like to modify their locations and replace them by {}[] for programming purposes (currently located on level 3 of keys 7 8 9 0 ).

I figured I should modify the file corresponding to Canadian Multilingual Standard layout. I found it in `/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols`, in the `ca` file. I modified the entries for "Canadian Multilingual", then called `setxkbmap ca multix`. Modifications didn't work.

I opened another Xserver window (sudo xinit -- :2), called `setxkbmap ca multi` again, no effect. I rebooted, to no avail. I still see the modifications in the config file.

Am I modyfing the good file? I ran `sudo find -name xkb -print` to see if I was modifying in the wrong folder, but all other folders named as is were empty/full of gibberish

P.S.: Using ubuntu 12.04

P.P.S.: I checked all folders in xkb/symbols, to no avail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem. It seems Ubuntu stores cached copies of the keyboard layouts in `/var/lib/xkb`.

What worked for me was deleting the xkm files in /var/lib/xkb: `sudo rm /var/lib/xkb/*.xkm` and logout and in again.

This solved the issue for me.